# Windows Phone 7 API + SSL

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to connect to an API, which is hosted on an SSL connection.

This is the crossdomain:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<cross-domain-policy>
  <allow-access-from domain="*" secure="true" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

That's all there is.

Now I try to connect, but I always get a security exception (no more info given).

Now the problem is that in Silverlight you have to have the Silverlight app hosted on ssl if you want to connect to an ssl service. (which I can understand).

But how do I enforce this for Windows Phone 7? It's not on ssl or something.

Worst thing: I don't know if the problem is the `secure="true"` part, since I cannot import a custom root cert in WP7 and thus I can't test locally with SSL.

**The same code hosted on a non ssl solution works perfectly.**

Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
var base64Creds = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:{1}", "username", "password"))); 

webClient.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + base64Creds;
```

`.Credentials` itself is not supported, so it seems.